# why are finite-dimensional subspaces closed?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a banach space.
Why is a finite dimensional subspace $A \subset X$ then a closed set?

Comment: Because it's complete?

Comment: Use the fact that Any finite-dimensional normed linear space is isomorphic to $\Bbb K^n$ for some $n$, where $\Bbb K=\Bbb C,\Bbb R$.

Comment: Use induction. Show that if $V$ is a closed subspace and $x \notin V$ then $V+\{x\}$ is closed.

Comment: It is a well known theorem that a linear subspace $Y$ of a topological linear space is closed and if $\operatorname{dim}(Y)=n$, then $Y$ and $(\mathbb{F}^n,\|\;\|_2)$ are isomorphic-homeomorphic ($\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$ depending on whether one is dealing with real or complex linear spaces. A proof of ti can be seen in Rudin's book on functional analysis  (pp: 16-17) or in Roko Alipranti's Hitchhiker's guide (3rd ed.) pp. 177-179).

Answer (score 2):

Edit: the answer below only works if X is a Hilbert space, while the result asked for in the question holds much more generally.

Let $e_1,...,e_d$ be an orthonormal basis of $A$. The linear map
$$X \to X, \qquad x \mapsto x - \sum_{k=1}^d \langle e_k, x\rangle e_k$$
is continuous (actually, it is 1-Lipschitz because it is an orthonormal projection).

Since $A$ is the kernel of this map, it is closed as the pre-image of $\{0\}$ by a continuous map.

Comment: Sorry, OP has not given any **inner product.**

Comment: @jlewk: the statement if the OP is true in any topological linear space.